# Creating a button programatically in OnCreateView (Fragment class)

Tags: java, android, xml, button, android-fragments

I am trying to implement to create a button programmatically in android in my fragment class. However after hours of searching, I could not find an appropriate solution to it.
Here is my xml code :

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="77dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.70"
                        android:background="#FFCDD2"
                        android:src="@drawable/airtel_round_s" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/airtelamt"
                        android:layout_width="188dp"
                        android:layout_height="77dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.45"
                        android:background="#FFCDD2"
                        android:text="Button" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/iciciBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="77dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.70"
                        android:background="#FFE0B2"
                        android:src="@drawable/icici_logo_s" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/iciciamt"
                        android:layout_width="188dp"
                        android:layout_height="77dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.45"
                        android:background="#FFE0B2"
                        android:text="Button" />
                </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

Can someone please guide me through it ??

Here is the screen shot of the app:
[image]

Comment: Where exactly you want to add the button (in which Layout)?

Comment: Inside the linear layout. The hierarchy must be the same as defined in the xml above.

Comment: 1) You want to create a `Button` that load programmatically this xml each time you click on it, or you want to programmatically add a `Button` in this xml? --- 2) In the second case, there are **3** `LinearLayout`(s) in your xml, so which one you are talking about?

Comment: 1) I want to programatically add a button to the xml. 2) I am talking about the inner (2nd) Linear Layout.

Comment: If you fixed number of Buttons then you design those buttons in your layout and set visibility=gone. and when you need those buttons then  change visibility=visible.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to repeat following layout in pragmatically ?

```
               <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="77dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.70"
                        android:background="#FFCDD2"
                        android:src="@drawable/airtel_round_s" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/airtelamt"
                        android:layout_width="188dp"
                        android:layout_height="77dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.45"
                        android:background="#FFCDD2"
                        android:text="Button" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

Then use `ListView`

1) modify your main xml like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

2) create a new xml file and paste

```
                   <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="77dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1.70"
                            android:background="#FFCDD2"
                            android:src="@drawable/airtel_round_s" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/airtelamt"
                            android:layout_width="188dp"
                            android:layout_height="77dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.45"
                            android:background="#FFCDD2"
                            android:text="Button" />
                    </LinearLayout>
```

3) create `Adapter` to fill `ListView`

Comment: Yes, the layout is been repeated.

Comment: I want to dynamically create button in my Fragment class. There is a condition that I have place in my Fragment class. if it is satisfied, then the button will be created. I cannot keep it static.

Answer (score 0):

You will get help for your problem from this :

```
ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<String>();

mList.add("Button 0");
mList.add("Button 1");
mList.add("Button 2");
// this has added 3 buttons

ListAdapter mAdapter = new ListAdaper(getApplicationContext, mList);

if( /* your condition */ ) {
    mList.add("Button "+i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"  
                    android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"><!-- i guess this is your LinearLayout-->

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="77dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.70"
                        android:background="#FFCDD2"
                        android:src="@drawable/airtel_round_s" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/airtelamt"
                        android:layout_width="188dp"
                        android:layout_height="77dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.45"
                        android:background="#FFCDD2"
                        android:text="Button" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/iciciBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="77dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.70"
                        android:background="#FFE0B2"
                        android:src="@drawable/icici_logo_s" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/iciciamt"
                        android:layout_width="188dp"
                        android:layout_height="77dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.45"
                        android:background="#FFE0B2"
                        android:text="Button" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

Then from java code:

```
  Button myButton = new Button(YourActivity.this);
    myButton.setText("new button");

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, weight);
    myButton.setLayoutParams(param);

    myButton.setBackgroundResource(YourResource); // like "android:src"
    myButton.setBackground(Drawable); // like "android:background"

   LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);

    ll.addView(myButton, param);
```

Comment: I got that. But I am still not able to get how to set the parameters of the the button like layout_weight, layout_height, android:background, android:src ??

Comment: Thanku...What about layout_weight ?

Comment: The **weight** field = **layout_weight**

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But there seem to be no error in the code. Not even a runtime error. However the button dosen't seem to form properly. I just see a red (the color that I set on the button) line that had some width.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? maybe there is something wrong in your button configuration (the value of weight, width...)

Comment: I did that below..Check it out !

Comment: The red line is the LinearLayout in which you have added the Button? or the Button is shown as a red line (after adding it to the view)?

Comment: I've updated the code. Sorry it was my mistake, i've set the LayoutParams two times... this is why it override your values